# MySQL: How to optimize this query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I almost spent a day to optimize this query:

```
SELECT 
    prod. *, 
    cat.slug category_slug, 
    sup.bname bname, 
    sup.slug bname_slug
FROM bb_admin.bb_directory_products AS prod
LEFT JOIN bb_admin.bb_categories_products AS cat 
    ON prod.primary_category_id = cat.category_id
LEFT JOIN bb_admin.bb_directory_suppliers AS sup 
    ON prod.supplier_id = sup.supplier_id
LEFT JOIN bb_admin.bb_directory_suppliers AS credit_sup 
    ON prod.credit_supplier_id = credit_sup.supplier_id
LEFT JOIN bb_admin.bb_directory_suppliers AS photo_sup 
    ON prod.photo_supplier_id = photo_sup.supplier_id
WHERE (
    prod.status = '1'
    OR prod.status = '3'
    OR prod.status = '5'
)
    AND (
        sup.active_package_id != '1'
        OR sup.active_package_id != '5'
        OR sup.active_package_id != '6'
        OR prod.supplier_id = '0'
    )
    AND (
        sup.supplier_id = '1989'
        OR credit_sup.supplier_id = '1989'
        OR photo_sup.supplier_id = '1989'
    )
GROUP BY prod.product_id
ORDER BY prod.priority_index ASC
```

Can you help me to optimized this query?

Comment: You can start by preventing `SELECT *`.

Comment: Create indexes, use `IN()` clause.

Comment: What is the performance issue?  How big are the tables?  What is the explain plan?

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: Use `IN()` and `NOT IN()` in query. But avoid **1:n** relationship in join. It will collect more number of rows. use **Explain Extended** before your query

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your column data types to be `INT` or one of its variants, since the ones you are checking against are all integer IDs (assumption).
2. Create indexes on following columns(if possible in all tables):

   - prod.status
   - supplier_id
   - active_package_id
3. Use `IN` clause instead of concatenating `OR` segments.

I'll be putting the updated `WHERE` clause here:

```
WHERE prod.status IN(1, 3, 5)
    AND ( sup.active_package_id NOT IN(1, 5, 6)
        OR prod.supplier_id = 0
    )
    AND 1989 IN (prod.supplier_id, prod.credit_supplier_id, prod.photo_supplier_id)
```